# OR-Tools VRP set Maximum Route per Vehicle using Distance Dimension

Tags: python, or-tools

I have a problem when calculating routes distance per vehicle

example
num vehicle: 9 
total address: 70

it's only return 6 venicles, and one of the vehicles has 36 routes applied

currently, I'm using the Distance dimension, i also already tried the "Counter" dimension, the results are correct based on the max route that we set, but the distance between points is random (example result: route 1 : 1KM, route 2 : 7KM, route 3: 2KM)

I want to set the limit per vehicle but using the "Distance" dimension

my code

```py
manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)


    # Create and register a transit callback.
    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]


    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Add Distance constraint.
    dimension_name = 'Distance'
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        0,  # no slack
        100000,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        dimension_name)
    distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
    distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When creating the Dimension

```py
routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        0,  # no slack
        100_000,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        dimension_name)
```

here `100_000` is the hard upper bound.

2. To have a specific limit per vehicle you can use the overload method
   `AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity()` which take a list instead of a value for the capacity aka max travel distance.
   ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b77bd3ac69b7f3bb02f55b7bab6cbb4bab3917f2/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L448-L451
3. For counter stuff if you want to "equally" distribute node you can use:

```py
  # Distribution
    routing.AddConstantDimension(
            1,
            manager.GetNumberOfNodes(),
            True, # start cumul to zero
            "Counter")
    counter_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie("Counter")
    nb_visit = (manager.GetNumberOfNodes()) // manager.GetNumberOfVehicles()
    print(f'visit_mean: {nb_visit}')
    penalty = 10_000 # must be adapted to your problem
    for vehicle_id in range(data["num_vehicles"]):
      index = routing.End(vehicle_id)
      counter_dimension.SetCumulVarSoftLowerBound(index, nb_visit, penalty)
      counter_dimension.SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound(index, nb_visit + 1, penalty)
```